# Symfony, how to check if strings are translated?

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, twig, translation

I would like to return a specific string each time a string is used in {% trans %}.

Exemple :

```
{% trans from 'base' %}home.title{% endtrans %}
```

Returns : "Home"

I would like it to return "XXX" and to automatically do it.

I used to do this in some pure PHP projects but I just don't know how to do it in Symfony.

Comment: Replace Home with XXX! Your question is unclear. Please try to ask a clear question to get better help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear how you decide XXX. Whatever  you did with pure PHP is doable with twig by means for twig filters. you can do something like `home.title|trans_base` and implement trans_base filter. See document under Filters section [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html)